# NuGet Packages Not Properly Restoring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

I cloned a project to a new computer. I restored my NuGet packages and everything appears to restore fine.

I'm running into some issues trying to build my solution. I'm getting the following errors:

> Error CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the
> namespace 'SimpleInjector.Integration.Web' (are you missing an
> assembly reference?)
>
> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name
> 'SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried reinstalling my NuGet packages

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```

I also checked my csproj file to make sure that the version numbers for Simple Injector are matching.

Comment: Do you have `SimpleInjector.Integration.Web` package in your package.config file mentioned?

Comment: Your first error looks like a namespace conflict. Your second error looks like a missing package.

Comment: Yes, I have SimpleInjector.Integration.Web in packages.config. Also I should note that it works just fine on my other computer that I was using previously. Not getting any errors, so I assume it's just an issue with those packages.

Comment: have you tried restoring the packages, rather than updating? `nuget restore`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your project file, find the references, and confirm the hint path is correct for the items in question. It should point to the packages folder nuget is restoring to.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you!